# How to change color of the Button after clicking it?

Tags: java, android, xml

I have dynamically created buttons. I just want change the background color of the button which I have clicked. For example, Initially all buttons should have grey background color. If I clicked a button then clicked button background color should changed to red and other buttons background color should be in grey.

Here I have tried a bit

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
 Button myBtn = new Button(ProductDetailsActivity.this);
 myBtn.setText("My Button"+i);
 myBtn.setBackGroundColor(Color.parseColor("#cccccc"));
 myBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View view) {
        myBtn.setBackGroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ff0000"));
     }
});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems legit.
But instead of

```
myBtn.setBackGroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ff0000"));
```

You can use

```
myBtn.setBackGroundColor(Color.RED);
```

I think you want to change all buttons' colors dynamically according to which one is clicked. And want to turn others to gray.

So to achieve that you need to keep buttons in an array. Then by reaching others index you can modify them. You can get the index from the end of the buttonText String and parse it to integer.

```
    Button[] buttonArray = new Button[4];

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
 Button myBtn = new Button(ProductDetailsActivity.this);
 myBtn.setText("My Button"+i);
 myBtn.setBackGroundColor(Color.GREY);
 myBtn.setId(new Random().nextInt());
 myBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View view) {

          for(int j=0; j<buttonArray.lenght;j++){
              if(view.getId() == buttonArray[j].getId()){
                   buttonArray[j].setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                }else{
                   buttonArray[j].setBackgroundColor(Color.GREY);
                }
             }
     }
});
 buttonArray[i]=myBtn;
}
```

**So the main idea is to keep all buttons in an array. If one of them clicked, get that one's index make it's background's red. And turn other buttons'(which is not that index) background grey again.**

Comment: its not working..... Showing error on
int redButtonIndex = Integer.parseInt(text.getText(text.getText().length()-1,text.getText().length()));

Comment: Can you  type the error please?

Comment: I corrected the code. If you use myBtn.getText.subString. Error will go away

Comment: My App gets crashed...

Comment: could you upvote my question?

Comment: You need to initialize  Button[] buttonArray = new Button[4]; as a global variable

Comment: And if you check the console and type the error i can help you with that

Comment: yes....
eventhough it make my app crashed